# Google Datastore 503

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

We're getting 503 when connecting to datastore for about 2 hours since now.
In the google console I'm getting "Backend error" when selecting anything associated to google datastore.

It's a problem for us because our business depends on this service.

Does anyone know what's going on ? ;) Maybe someone have the same issue right now ?

https://status.cloud.google.com/ <--- it's showing that everything is allright but it's not ;((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have run out of quota. You should check the quota status of your application. For more information take a look at [Quotas](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas).

Comment: It's not that. We're paying for the service so we don't have a limit for that ;/ theoretically.

Comment: You're right. It was a daily quota - we had unusual traffic today and everyone forgot about this ( setting this some time ago we thought that we have more than we need ) 

Thanks for Your help !

Comment: @DamianMariuszDąbrowski, it's great that Thanos's answer has helped -- so now please *accept* it, that's the etiquette on this site!